# Show $X$ is connected, given that $G$ and $X/G$ are connected

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a connected topological group and $G \times X \to X$ be a continuous group action such that $X/G$ is connected.

> Show that X is connected

**My idea:**

Let $U, V \subseteq X$ be open, disjoint with $U \cup V = X$. For a fix $x \in X,$ we have $$Gx = U \cap Gx \bigcup V \cap Gx.$$
Since the action is continuous and $G$ is connected, we have that $U \cap Gx = \emptyset$ or $V \cap Gx = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by saying, as you do, that the action of $G$ preserves the connected components of $X$. I look at this as: if $x\in U$, then $\mu =-\cdot x:G\rightarrow X$ is a continuous function, so that $G = \mu^{-1}(U) \cup \mu^{-1}(V)$ is the union of disjoint open sets. But since $G$ is connected and $e\in\mu^{-1}(U)$, there is no $g\in \mu^{-1}(V)$, i.e. such that $gx\in V$.

What this means is that no point in $U$ is equivalent to a point in $V$. Denoting the quotient map by $q:X\rightarrow X/G = q(U)\cup q(V)$, we thus have $q(U)\cap q(V) = \emptyset$. But by definition of the quotient topology both $q(U)$ and $q(V)$ are open sets, and since the quotient space is connected we must thus have $q(V)=\emptyset$, implying that $V=\emptyset$.